# Compose up recreating the compose Service created by other directories

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I used multiple `docker-compose.yaml` to start `multiple services` to `mount data` from the sensors for different periods of time for subsequent data reads.
But when I run the `docker-compose up` command in a different directory, I discover that it will affect the service I started earlier.
The directory and code are as follows:

**7-11-am**

```
#  ~/Datasets/7-11/am
version: '3.7'

services:
    sensor-db:
        image: influxdb:1.7.6
        container_name: sensordb-7-11-am
        ports:
            - "8183:8086"
        volumes:
            - $PWD/.influxdb:/var/lib/influxdb
```

**7-11-pm**

```
#  ~/Datasets/7-11/pm
version: '3.7'

services:
    sensor-db:
        image: influxdb:1.7.6
        container_name: sensordb-7-11-pm
        ports:
            - "8184:8086"
        volumes:
            - $PWD/.influxdb:/var/lib/influxdb
```

**7-13-pm**

```
# ~/Datasets/7-13/pm

version: '3.7'

services:
    sensor-db:
        image: influxdb:1.7.6
        container_name: sensordb-7-13-pm
        ports:
            - "8188:8086"
        volumes:
            - $PWD/.influxdb:/var/lib/influxdb
```

When I start the first two time periods using `docker-compose up` it doesn't send recreating problems, and when I run the service to mount the data on the 7-13 afternoon, I find that the docker-compose up output is recreating sensordb-7-11-pm, and then the sensordb-7-11-pm is replaced by the sensordb-7-13-pm service via the `docker ps` command

This is not what I expected, `the container names of the services` are not the same, but why do they affect each other?

But I don't know how to find the relevant problem.

I would appreciate it if you could tell me why the problem arose and how it could be resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compose has a notion of a *project name*, and a *service name* within that project.  The default project name is the base name of the directory holding the `docker-compose.yml` file.  In your case, even though you have three directories and three `docker-compose.yml` files, from Compose's point of view you have only two "projects" named `am` and `pm`.

When you run the "7-13-pm" file, Compose looks for a container matching the project name `pm` and the service name `sensor-db`.  It finds that (from the `sensordb-7-11-pm` container) and so it replaces it.  It doesn't matter that you've overridden the default `container_name:`.

The easiest workaround to this is just to rename the directories.  Instead of `7-11/pm` and `7-13/pm`, rename these to `7-11-pm` and `7-13-pm`, removing a layer of hierarchy.  You can also set the [`COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/#compose_project_name) environment variable or use the `docker-compose -p` option to set the project name (on every single `docker-compose` invocation; this wouldn't be my preference).